# Trouble with Google Maps v3 customMarker anchor point

Tags: javascript, maps

I have developed a map with custom marker Icons. The lat lng  coordinates are brought in from a json file. My problem though is that instead defining each and every marker we grouped them all together in an if statement for banner markers. My problem is that I want to use an if statement inside another one to make one banner appear differently.

Here is the code:

```
     if (is_featured == true){
    if (ad_id == 93){
        var marker_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "_files/ads/70/" +  mark[93] + "m.png",
            new google.maps.Size(91, 64),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(45.5, 64));
        info = get_sponsor_info(mark);   
        var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "_files/ads/70/" +  mark[93] + "ms.png",
            new google.maps.Size(126, 64),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(45.5, 64));
    }
    else {
        var marker_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "_files/ads/70/" +  mark['ad_id'] + "m.png",
            new google.maps.Size(140, 63),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(70, 63));
        info = get_sponsor_info(mark);   
        var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            "_files/ads/70/" +  mark['ad_id'] + "ms.png",
            new google.maps.Size(176, 63),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(70, 63));

        var banner_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pt,
            icon: marker_icon,
            map: map,
            zIndex: 100000000,
            shadow: shadow 


    })};
```

The anchor value in the if (ad_id ==93) does not affect the actual anchor point of the banner.

Need help asap. The map is here:

http://www.noblood.org/transfusion-alternatives-blood-management-resources-map

And you can see that the banner in Ohio should be right at the red x in Columbus but it's not.